# gulp-nunjucks-render is taking a lot of time to compile

Tags: gulp, nunjucks, gulp-nunjucks-render

I am using gulp-nunjucks-render for HTML templating.

The problem is, it is taking more than 3-4 minutes to compile. Even though I have only seven nunjucks templates.

```
'use strict';

var gulp = require('gulp'),
    autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer'),
    sass = require('gulp-sass'),
    minifyCSS = require('gulp-minify-css'),
    uglify = require('gulp-uglify'),
    concat = require('gulp-concat'),
    connect = require('gulp-connect'),
    sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps'),
    nunjucksRender = require('gulp-nunjucks-render'),
    browserSync = require('browser-sync');

gulp.task('html', function(){
  gulp.src('build/*.html')
    .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream: true}))
});

gulp.task('nunjucksRender', function(){
  gulp.src('sources/html/**/*.+(html|nunjucks)')
  .pipe(nunjucksRender({
      path: ['sources/html/']
  }))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('build/'))
  .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream: true}))
});

gulp.task('css', function(){
  gulp.src('sources/scss/main.scss')
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(sass({outputStyle: 'expanded'})
      .on('error', sass.logError)
    )
    .pipe(autoprefixer({
      browsers: ['last 50 versions']
    }))
    // .pipe(minifyCSS())
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write(''))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build/css'))
    .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream: true}))
});

gulp.task('js', function() {
  gulp.src('sources/**/*.js',)
    // concat pulls all our files together before minifying them
    .pipe( concat('main.min.js') )
    // .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build/js'))
    .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream: true}))
});

gulp.task('watch', function(){
  gulp.watch('build/*.html', ['html', 'nunjucksRender']);
  gulp.watch('sources/**/*.nunjucks', ['nunjucksRender']);
  gulp.watch('sources/scss/**/*.scss', ['css']);
  gulp.watch('sources/js/**/*.js', ['js']);
});

gulp.task('browserSync', function(){
  browserSync({
    server: {
      baseDir: 'build'
    }
  });
});

gulp.task('default', ['css', 'html']);

gulp.task('start', ['browserSync', 'watch']);
```

Here is how it looks like when compilation is finished
[image]

Is there any gulp plugin to reduce compile time or compile only those files which are changed?

[here](https://github.com/hello-ajayrawat/Admin-Theme) is the github repo in case you need to see full file structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah.. I was watching `.html` and `.nunjucks` files for changes.. so when .nunjucks file compiles and creates `.html` file then again `.html` related task runs.